# Paypal Pro integration without any round trip to paypal website using paypal account

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I want to do paypal integration with my website such as we can do all payment with paypal account without going on paypal website.
and i want to do login for user to payment from own website not from paypal website. and finally pay should also from own website.
in all these process i just want to use paypal account not credit card and debit card.
Can any one provide me solutions or source code in asp.net ?

Comment: This is not possible. For security reasons, you must redirect to Paypal for users to be able to login.

Comment: can we do above process with recurring payments with paypal account ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if you can keep the buyer on your site, and allow them to set up a recurring payment with their PayPal account without sending them over to PayPal, the answer is NO.  If you are asking if you can redirect the buyer over to PayPal and have them set up a recurring payment, the answer is YES.

Comment: Hi, If I click on final checkout button after finding paykey in adaptive payment then it redirects on login page of paypal. I just want to not redirect on login page of paypal, i want to redirect on own login page for payment approval to user and after this user can pay also final pay on own website . Is it posible ?